# Combining Twitter JSONs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, twitter

I'm trying to create a feed to display the combined results of 3 queries to the Twitter API, since there seems to be no way to get what I want with one API call (2 user timelines and 1 search result for a hashtag). I want the results to be sorted by date so that the most recent appears at the start (just like when I get a result back from the Twitter API).

How can I combine these 3 JSONs (from the Twitter API), whilst maintaining the date order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways of doing this. i would probably persist all the stuff in a database.

that comes with several benefits:

first of all, caching is super easy, you can fetch the data from your own database until it gets stale.

secondly, databases are reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaly good at sorting and all this date shizzle. it's hard doing this manually and usually slow. i tend to mess it up all the time, so i let the database do the job for me.

Comment: I'm actually creating this using RhoMobile and RhoConnect, so RhoConnect caches everything in a database for me. The code that I'm writing here just needs to fetch/update the data from Twitter, so I feel like a database here might be unnecessary.

Comment: so then `sort_by` is your friend

Comment: Thanks, but I think my original question was poorly researched. I combined the three items like this: `combined = [json1, json2, json3].map{ |s| JSON[s] }.flatten.to_json` and then sorted them in my controller by just using `@twitters = Twitter.find(:all, :order => ['created_at'], :orderdir => ['DESC'])`. This might not be the perfect solution but it works well for what I need.